# Unable to open the txt files in a folder

Tags: c, fopen, file-handling, dirent.h

I have a set of txt files in a folder. These txt files have ASCII values, and I am converting the ASCII values to decimal values and storing them in an excel file (CSV). I am able to run the code and get correct results for one file where I manually provide the name of the file containing ASCII values as well as the CSV file.

Now, my goal is to automate this process for all the txt files in the folder. Currently, in my code attached below, I am manually providing the CSV file name where I want to store the decimal data (I will later modify my code such that the data from each txt file is stored in a new csv file, but for now I am just providing the filename). I am trying to get the file name using the functions in `dirent.h` header file. But I am getting a segmentation fault at line `fp1=fopen(entry->d_name,"r");`. I am not sure what is causing the problem. Can someone please help me resolve the issue so that I am able to loop through all the text files?

Thank you.

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void scan_dir(const char *dir)
{
    FILE *fp1,*fp2;
    struct dirent * entry;
    DIR *d = opendir( dir );
    char c;
    int dec=0,k=0,stop=0;

    if (d == 0) {
        perror("opendir");
        return;
    }

    while ((entry = readdir(d)) != 0) {
        printf("%s\n", entry->d_name);
        const char *dot = strrchr(entry->d_name, '.');
        printf("%s\n",dot+1);
        if(!(strcmp(dot+1,"txt"))){
        //read your file here
            fp1=fopen(entry->d_name,"r");
            fp2 = fopen("decimal.csv","w");
            while((c=fgetc(fp1))!=EOF){ /*code to convert ASCII values to decimal*/
                dec=dec | c<< (8*k);
                k++;
                if(k==4){
                    k=0;
                    dec =dec>>14;
                    fprintf(fp2,"%d\n",dec);
                    //printf("%d\n",dec);
                    if(dec==-1){
                    stop=1;
                }
                dec=0;
            }
            if(stop==1){
                stop=0;
                break;
            }
            }
        }
        fclose(fp1);
        fclose(fp2);
    }
    closedir(d);
}

int main()
{
    scan_dir("C:/Users/Downloads/Newfolder");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Add more error checking. Check whether `fopen` and all other function calls succeed or not. On failure call `perror` to get a more specific error message.

Comment: The name in `entry->d_name` does *not* include the directory name, it's only the actual file name. You need to make sure to add the directory name as well. And of course to make sure that the full relative path name is correct in relation to the current [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory).

Comment: One issue: `fgetc` returns an `int` not a `char`. `EOF` cannot fit in a `char` so your loop is probably infinete.

Comment: As `d_name` is an array, it cannot be `NULL`. Therefore I cannot see how `fp1=fopen(entry->d_name,"r");` could cause a segfault unless `entry` is `NULL`. But you already print it a few lines above. You should get the segfault or `(nul)` output already there. Or your segfault happens somewhere else. Maybe you mean when you use `fp1` from that `fopen` call?

Comment: You close `fp1` and `fp2` for each iteration of your loop even if you did not open the files at all. You either pass uninitialized pointer to `fclose` or the invalid pointer from last iteration. That invokes undefined behaviour and could cause your segfault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line

```
fp1=fopen(entry->d_name,"r");
```

entry->d_name is the name of the file without the path so the file can be found and the pointer fp1 will be null,
more over the file were closed without been opened an this bring out the crash.

The first part of you function could be fixed in the following way

```
static void scan_dir(const char *dir)
{
    FILE *fp1,*fp2;
    struct dirent * entry;
    DIR *d = opendir( dir );
    char c;
    int dec=0,k=0,stop=0;

    if (d == 0) {
        perror("opendir");
        return;
    }

    while ((entry = readdir(d)) != 0) {
        printf("%s\n", entry->d_name);
        char fname[256];
        strcpy(fname,dir);
        strcat(fname, entry->d_name);
        const char *dot = strrchr(entry->d_name, '.');
        printf("%s\n",dot+1);
        if(!(strcmp(dot+1,"txt"))){
        //read your file here
            fp1=fopen(fname,"r");
            fp2 = fopen("decimal.csv","w");
            while((c=fgetc(fp1))!=EOF){ /*code to convert ASCII values to decimal*/
                dec=dec | c<< (8*k);
                k++;
                if(k==4){
                    k=0;
                    dec =dec>>14;
                    fprintf(fp2,"%d\n",dec);
                    printf("%d\n",dec);
                    if(dec==-1){
                    stop=1;
                }
                dec=0;
            }
            if(stop==1){
                stop=0;
                break;
            }
            }
            fclose(fp1);
            fclose(fp2);
        }
    }
    closedir(d);
}
```

then you have to modify the saving in the cvs file because you replace the previous converted dec value with the last one .